# Why locking a std::mutex doesn't block the thread

Tags: c++, c++11, concurrency

I wrote the following code to test my understanding of `std::mutex`

```
int main() {
    mutex m;
    m.lock();
    m.lock(); // expect to block the thread
}
```

And then I got a `system_error: device or resource busy`. Isn't the second `m.lock()` supposed to block the thread?

Comment: there's only one thread, why would it be useful to get it blocked?

Comment: Other threads will block; there's no guarantee the mutex-owning tread will (and in fact this version produces an error.)

Comment: If that second call blocked the thread, how would the thread get unblocked?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From [`std::mutex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex):

> A calling thread must not own the mutex prior to calling lock or try_lock.

and from [`std::mutex::lock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/lock):

> If lock is called by a thread that already owns the mutex, the program may deadlock. Alternatively, if an implementation can detect the deadlock, a resource_deadlock_would_occur error condition may be observed.

and the *exceptions* clause:

> Throws std::system_error when errors occur, including errors from the underlying operating system that would prevent lock from meeting its specifications. The mutex is not locked in the case of any exception being thrown.

Therefore it is not supposed to block the thread. On your platform, the implementation appears to be able to detect when a thread is already the owner of a lock and raise an exception. This may not happen on other platforms, as indicated in the descriptions.

Comment: I'm trying `std::mutex m;std::thread([&]{m.lock();}).detach();m.lock();`, but it's still not blocking. (Arch Linux gcc 8.2.0)

Answer (score 9):

> Isn't the second `m.lock()` supposed to block the thread?

No, it gives undefined behaviour. The second `m.lock()` breaks this requirement:

> C++11 30.4.1.2/7 *Requires:* If m is of type `std::mutex` or `std::timed_mutex`, the calling thread does not own the mutex.

It looks like your implementation is able to detect that the calling thread owns the mutex and gives an error; others may block indefinitely, or fail in other ways.

Answer (score 2):

(`std::mutex` wasn't mentioned in the question when I wrote this answer.)

It depends on the mutex library and mutex type you're using - you haven't told us.  Some systems provide a "recursive mutex" that is allowed to be called multiple times like this only if it happens from the same thread (then you must have a matching number of unlocks before another thread can lock it), other libraries consider this an error and may fail gracefully (as yours has) or have undefined behaviour.

Comment: std mutex is not recursive

Comment: even if it were recursive, it would not block. A recursive mutex locks a 2nd time and waits for 2 unlocks. It will block a second thread though.

Comment: The library is the C++11 standard library, and the mutex type is `std::mutex`. That isn't a recursive mutex; that's called `std::recursive_mutex`. And the behaviour here isn't recursive; it's giving an error when trying to acquire a second lock.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: the question didn't mention std::mutex when I wrote this answer - that should be obvious from the "you haven't told us".  And, as the question showed surprise at the behaviour, I've contrasted the behaviour of recursive mutexes and non-recursive, then explicitly said "(as yours has)" for the behaviour described for a non-recursive mutex....

Comment: @TonyD: I guess that must have been added to the question too quickly to show up in the edit history. Sorry if I implied that you misread the question.